How to create text in Flutter like this
I am new to flutter, I want a text to look like the below image.
Here's the image :

This is what i have tried and it didn't work.
Expanded(
  child: Positioned(
    top: 300,
    left: 165,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "Budget",
          style: GoogleFonts.aBeeZee(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 36, 65),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Budget",
              style: GoogleFonts.aBeeZee(
                fontSize: 36,
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 36, 65),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              "Budget",
              style: GoogleFonts.aBeeZee(
                fontSize: 22,
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 36, 65),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
),


You can solve your problem using RichText and TextSpan like this:
RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: '1200',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontSize: 32,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: ' / 500 ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

And this output :
output

Text.rich Widget also work
